# How can we check the forecast accuracy in time series?

Tags: python, machine-learning, time-series

I am getting accuracy as **0** in the VAR model time series. How can we check the forecast accuracy in time series using Python?

```
print("df_results['Field1_f']", df_results['Field1_f'])
print("df_test['Field1']", df_test['Field1'])    

print("accuracy:")   
print(accuracy_score(df_test['Field1'], df_results['Field1_f']))
```

Please find below the output for reference.

```
df_results['Field1_f'] 

179    1792622
180    1794414
181    1670866
182    1842468
183    1793253
184    1647436
185    1944522
186    1857092
187    1744014
188    1742659
Name: Field1_f, dtype: int32

df_test['Field1'] 

189    1750000
190    1970000
191    1537000
192    1400000
193    1890100
194    1970000
195    1770000
196    1729000
197    1940000
198    2150000
Name: Field1, dtype: int64

accuracy:
0.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using `accuracy_score` from scikit-learn, it is **not** the correct measure here; accuracy is meant for classification problems, not for numerical prediction ones, such as forecasting problems. From the [docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html#sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score):

> Accuracy classification score.

Most common error metrics for forecasting problems are the MSE, RMSE, and MAE; all of them are available in scikit-learn under "Regression" [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#common-cases-predefined-values):

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error

mean_squared_error(df_test['Field1'], df_results['Field1_f'])  # MSE

mean_squared_error(df_test['Field1'], df_results['Field1_f'],
                                      squared=False)           # RMSE

mean_absolute_error(df_test['Field1'], df_results['Field1_f']) # MAE
```

---

Keep in mind that, in an ML context, the term "accuracy" does not have the exact same meaning with its every-day usage; in ML it normally means *classification accuracy*, which, as already said, is applicable to classification problems only - although, to be honest, in forecasting the term is indeed used with its every-day meaning...

Answer (score 0):

Since none of the values in your predicted list and result list are matching the accuracy will be zero.

Accuracy in time series is not be a very good judging factor to check the performance of time series forecasting. Instead of that you should try plotting the result in time as X axis and your values as Y axis.

Another powerful metric which you can try is root mean squared error.